# Partitioning in a Win / Ubuntu dual boot over 2 Tb HDD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, windows-10, kali

I have a 2.8 TB HDD with Windows 10 installed. It's broken into:

- 100 MB system recovery partition
- 2 TB NTFS `C:` drive primary partition
- 450 MB system reserved primary partition
- 750 GB unallocated

I understand that the 750 GB unallocated is due to the non-GPT drive and the 2 TB limit.

What I'd like to do, is install a dual boot set up with Ubuntu or possibly a triple boot set up with Kali.

I went into Gparted in the Ubuntu install and got errors preventing me from partitioning the unallocated part into a primary or extended partition.

How can I utilize this space for parallel Linux installations?

Comment: When asking questions you need to be specific.  *What* errors did you get from gparted?  Also a screen shot of gparted or a copy/paste of the output of `sudo parted -l` would help.

Comment: The error seems connected to the 2 Tb limit: it states "starting sector number 4294967296 exceeds the msdos partition table imposed maximum of 4294967295"

Answer (score 0):

Then you will need to either reformat the drive, convert to GPT, and boot in UEFI mode ( assuming your motherboard supports it -- windows won't boot from GPT otherwise, though Linux is fine with bios mode ), or if you shrink your windows partitions a bit so that the free space begins below the 2 TiB mark, then I believe you can create an Ubuntu partition that *starts* below that point, but extends beyond it.  Your bios may or may not actually be capable of handling that.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows,there is a way to convert MBR to GPT without reinstalling OS if your system and hardware support UEFI. If you want to convert MBR to GPT without affecting the OS, you need to use third party software,

such as AOMEI Partition Assistant. After the conversion, you have to enable UEFI boot mode before booting your computer, otherwise, you computer will fail to boot. However, the free version only available for converting non-system disk.

In Windows,there also is a way to use the space beyond 2TB without converting MBR to GPT. You can use Seagate Disc Wizard to mount the unallocated space as a virtual drive, so you can read or write with it.